# Count array elements after the given element

Tags: php, arrays

How to count array elements after the first occurrence of a given element?

For example

```
 $a = array('a', 'c','xxd','ok','next1','next2');
 echo occurences_after($a, 'ok');
```

should print "2"

Comment: What is the question again?

Comment: Perhaps you should post in english.stackexchange.com before attempting to ask a programming question ;-)

Comment: Why is the the number of next 'ok' is 2?

Comment: Seems to be a little bit of confusion, as the example you give doesn't seem to match the question. Do you want to count elements in an array or count the occurrences of a value in an array?

Comment: this question just blew my mind...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for the number of elements after the first occurrence of a given element:

```
function occurences_after($array, $element)
{
  if ( ($pos = array_search($element, $array)) === false) 
    return false;
  else
    return count($array) - $pos - 1;
}
```

Comment: A brave, possibly inspired, attempt at decryption =) +1

Comment: That would be my guess as to the meaning of this question

Answer (score 1):

```
$counts = array_count_values($value);
```

[PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$number_of_elements = count($A)
```

Reference: [manual page on `count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, the way to count the number of elements that match a particular element in an array is to loop over the array and check each element individually for a match. This smells like homework, so I'm not going to write the code for you, because it's trivial, but it should get you going in the right direction.

So to reiterate:

- loop over every element in the array
- check each element to see if it
  matches the requirement
- if it does,
  increment the number of items found

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean.
If you want to count the amount of elements in the array $A.

You can use `count($A)`

If you want to count the values:

```
print_r(array_count_values($A));
```

**The output will be:**

```
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [c] => 1
    [xxd] => 1
    [ok] => 1
    [next1] => 1
    [next2] => 1
)
```